# Performance of Struts2 based application

Tags: performance, networking, jboss, struts2

My question can seem to be novice, but I really want to know ,is there any way by which I can increase Struts2 based web application performance if my network is slow .

Comment: If the network is the bottleneck, all you can do is upgrade your network.

Comment: If the network is slow, and the design of your application is efficient, the only solution is improving your network as it has nothing to do with your application.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the network is slow, then the challenge is to send as much as required in the smallest size.

1. Minify your scripts/stylesheets
2. Enable compression on server
3. Use [PageSpeed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-speed-insights-with/lanlbpjbalfkflkhegagflkgcfklnbnh?hl=en) in chrome to figure out what else can be done to make it faster. It'll probably be related to using SVGs, sprites, caching.
4. Send only required information/data to the front-end.
5. Removing un-necessary spacing from JSPs can help reduce the size a bit if you're using too many of them.

Above points applies to all webapps, there is nothing Struts2 specific. But implementation can be Struts2 specific.

For example, if a Struts2 action sends a JSON with 100 fields out of which only 20 are required, then modify the action to send only required fields.

Modify the actions to be intelligent to ignore subsequent requests for nearly constant data and instead send `304`.

For example, consider list of products not changing frequently, but on every page we make a request to fetch the products. Now the action can see if there is a change in the products then send the new list or simply send `304` http status code . The front-end can simply store the products in a js variable in the first call itself and on getting 304 simply reuse it.

Hope this gives a good idea on in what direction to proceed.

Comment: Kudos to you ,,, lots of useful information given by you